# Public URL to files in Google Cloud Storage from python backend (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing an Android application, which communicates with backend Google App Engine written in Python. User is uploading and downloading files to Google Cloud Storage. So far, the files where being sent to the GAE backend by POST request, and then saved in GCS. I want user to do it directly to GCS (to avoid sending large files over POST). And (on download request) I would like to send user only public URL to file. There is a nice tutorial for it in PHP: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload and
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/public_access and key sentence there:  "Once the file is written to Cloud Storage as publically readable, you need to get the public URL for the file, using CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl." How to do the same in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public URL of a file in GCS looks like this:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<appname>.appspot.com/<filename>
```

When I store files in GCS, I explicitly give the file a filename, so I can create a serving URL using the template above.

Are you giving a filename when you store files in GCS?  If not, are you able to do so?  Maybe provided details of how you are saving the files to GCS in your question to get a better answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm creating files with gcs.open(filename, options...). So, is it enough to make a file public by setting right 'x-goog-acl' option when creating file?

Comment: I haven't done that myself, but it sounds like it would work.  Please try and let us know.

Comment: Yes, what needs to be done is to set 'x-goog-acl' to any option which allows reading (such as "public-read") and then we can use link as you showed. Thank you!